# Which maps I can use to track a fleet of vehicles?

Tags: gps, maps, tracking

I have a project to track a fleet vehicles, each with a GPS device on board that sends its coordinates at regular intervals of time, I was going to use google maps for this purpose but I found that for such a thing should have a license which costs quite a bit. And even with Bings is the same speech.

So I come to my question which maps (free) I can use to track a fleet of vehicles? There are other providers of maps to do a similar project?

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use http://www.openstreetmap.org/ ?